# Calculating median using two columns

Tags: excel

I have the following columns

```html
12 A
11 M
12 B
12 C
11 A
9 M
13 N
11 M
12 C
11 B
15 M
```

I want to calculate median based on only  Ms. I have done by selecting ranges.

I want to use columns rather than ranges. Is there any solution? Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "use columns rather than ranges"?

Comment: No. Do you think VBA is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2010 or later use this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(17,6,(A:A/(B:B="M")),2)
```

If you have 2007 or earlier, try this array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(B:B="M",A:A))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Though the use of full column references will slow the calculation times because it will iterate through all the rows, all 1.04 million.  It is good practice to limit the references to the max data range to help offset this drain.  Change the C:C to something like $C$1:$C$10000 then it will loop only 10,000 times.

Comment: By referencing entire columns, each of those solutions is astonishingly resource-heavy.

Comment: @XORLX the OP wrote `I want to use columns rather than ranges` so I obliged.  But you are correct limiting the full column references to the max data limits would speed up the calculations.  Though also I am assuming that this is a one off formula and the speed of calculation would not be compounded and therefore not be oppressive.

Comment: Perhaps, though I thought I should add the comment in any case, lest visitors to this page come away with the misguided impression that no detriment to calculation performance is suffered by referencing an arbitrary number of rows. Perhaps it might also have been better to query the OP rather than to make that assumption?

Comment: @XORLX I put a note at the end.

Comment: Scott- Why you have used 17, not 12, would you also explain 2. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @User20100 12 does not allow an array input, 17 is quartile and allows arrays.  Using the 2 on the end gives the median. See [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54V36oY6_d0) Video for a better explanation.

Comment: @User20100 did the above work for you?  If so, please consider marking as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click the green check mark by the answer you feel is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Well as a VBA user I love to use VBA, other can use your skill using formulas, and is completly right if you are good on formulas. Here is my answer and I hope help you.

Imagine you have this:

```
+----+------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  1 | Values (A) | Criteria Range (B) | Criteria ( C) |
+----+------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  2 |         14 | B                  | A             |
|  3 |          1 | M                  |               |
|  4 |         15 | A                  |               |
|  5 |         15 | E                  |               |
|  6 |         10 | A                  |               |
|  7 |          3 | M                  |               |
|  8 |         11 | A                  |               |
|  9 |          8 | M                  |               |
| 10 |         14 | A                  |               |
| 11 |          5 | M                  |               |
| 12 |          9 | M                  |               |
| 13 |         10 | M                  |               |
| 14 |         11 | N                  |               |
| 15 |          9 | A                  |               |
| 16 |          2 | M                  |               |
| 17 |         15 | M                  |               |
| 18 |         11 | A                  |               |
| 19 |         12 | S                  |               |
| 20 |          9 | M                  |               |
| 21 |         11 | A                  |               |
| 22 |         15 | V                  |               |
+----+------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

And inside the cell E2 you have this `=MedianIf($A$2:$A$22,$B$2:$B$22,C2)` and the result must be `11`

Because in a regular module of VBA you put this function.

```
Function MEDIANIF(RangeIf As Range, Criteria_Range1 As Range, Criteria1 As String) As Double
    Dim i
    Dim Counter
    Dim tmp()
    Dim subCouter
    subCouter = 0
    For Each i In Criteria_Range1
        Counter = Counter + 1
        If i.Value = Criteria1 Then
            subCouter = subCouter + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To subCouter)

            tmp(subCouter) = RangeIf(Counter)
        End If
    Next i
    Dim a
    MEDIANIF = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(tmp())
End Function
```

And the function works like this:

```
RangeIF = is the range with the values that you want to get the MEDIAN
Criteria_Range1 = Is the range where you have all the criteria, is the same size as RangeIF
Criteria1 = Is the criteria you use to filter the data.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this low-tech solution:

1. In Column C, formulate: **=IF(B2="M",A2,"")** (in rows 2-12, based on your data, and assuming row 1 contains headers)
2. In cell D2 (or anywhere else), formulate: **=MEDIAN(C:C)**